# Чтение данных с клавиатуры командной строки Windows без переноса курсора на следующую строку

Tags: java, input

Как реализовать чтение данных с клавиатуры без переноса курсора консоли на следующую строку с помощью Java? Конкретно в командной строке Windows.

`java.util.Scanner` переносит курсор на следующую строку своим методом, точно так же как и `java.io.Console`.

Насколько мне известно, вернуть курсор на предыдущую строку консоли в Java невозможно.

```
public static String Read() {
  Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  return Sc.next();
}

System.out.print("Turn of player: "); 
TempPlayerGuess = Integer.parseInt(Read()); 
System.out.print(".");
```

Консоль выдаёт:

> Turn of player: 4
>   .

Но мне хотелось бы увидеть:

> Turn of player: 4.

Comment: Из коробки мне ничего не известно. Может быть, это поможет: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Comment: Курс переносит Scanner.nextLine(). Что насчёт Scanner.next()

Comment: @danpetruk Только что попробовал! Всё равно переносится(

Comment: Как-то столкнулся при изучении джавы с подобным таском, в тот раз пришлось сделать окошко-эмулятор консоли и полностью контролировать вывод, теперь я прогю на c#;)

Answer (score 2):

В Windows любое чтение из стандартного ввода срабатывает только после ввода строки пользователем полностью. Это сделано для того, чтобы дать пользователю возможность хоть минимально, но редактировать вводимый текст. Таким образом, ни один из методов ввода, основанных на чтении из stdin, не даст решения этой задачи.

Если в Linux можно управлять терминалом через escape-последовательности - то в Windows этот трюк не работает, надо использовать [Windows Console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx). К сожалению для вас, Java не предоставляет доступа к этому API - так что JNI вам в помощь.

Comment: А можно вернуться на предыдущую строку?
@Pavel Mayorov